# Reference Error for logger that lies in for-each

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript and have the following class:

```
const Product = require('../models').Product

class ProductService {

    constructor(log) {
        this.logger = log
    }

    async generateIssuerRatingChangeContent(id, helperService, productService) {
        let products
        try {
            products = await productService.getproductByid(id)
        } catch (error) {
            this.logger.error(error)
        }
        this.logger.info("Get #products: " + products.length)

        let contentArr = []
        this.logger.info("##############Start to clean products##############")
        products.forEach(async function (item) {

            const res = {
               //...
            }

            let resultString = await helperService.stringCleaner(res)
            contentArr.push(resultString)
            this.logger.info(resultString); // <--- HERE I get an ReferenceError!!!
            console.log(resultString);
            this.logger.info("#####################-DONE WITH " + item.id + "-#####################");
        });
        await helperService.writeContentToFile(contentArr)

    }
}

module.exports = {
    ProductService
};
```

I am currently getting an error for the `logger` instance that lies within the for-each loop.

Why can't I access it with `this`?

Appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context changes when you define the callback with the `function` keyword. Instead, try using an arrow function, which will inherit the parent context (`this`).

```
const Product = require('../models').Product

class ProductService {

    constructor(log) {
        this.logger = log
    }

    async generateIssuerRatingChangeContent(id, helperService, productService) {
        let products
        try {
            products = await productService.getproductByid(id)
        } catch (error) {
            this.logger.error(error)
        }
        this.logger.info("Get #products: " + products.length)

        let contentArr = []
        this.logger.info("##############Start to clean products##############")
        products.forEach(async (item) => {

            const res = {
               //...
            }

            let resultString = await helperService.stringCleaner(res)
            contentArr.push(resultString)
            this.logger.info(resultString); // <--- HERE I get an ReferenceError!!!
            console.log(resultString);
            this.logger.info("#####################-DONE WITH " + item.id + "-#####################");
        });
        await helperService.writeContentToFile(contentArr)

    }
}

module.exports = {
    ProductService
};
```